# How to fork a new branch from a repo when you already have the master?

Tags: git, github

I have forked a repo into my own github account and have successfully pulled it to my PC, however there is now a new branch on the original repo that I want as well but when I try to fork that branch, it takesme to the master branch on my github account without actually doing anything. How do I get both branches on my account.

Comment: Fetch from wherever you want, the upstream github repo for instance.  Add a remote for it rather than just using the url.  Communication between repos is entirely arbitrary..

Comment: Would this be for use from command line or github? I was trying to get it onto my account then pull it down with command line. I'm very new to git so a lot of the commands are unfamiliar to me.

Comment: Github's not really where most real work gets done, it's for the meta stuff

Answer (score 18):

Once you have cloned your fork, you can on your local cloned repo add a new remote referencing the original repo (the one you have forked, and the one where a new branch of interest just appeared)

It is the [triangular workflow](https://github.com/blog/2042-git-2-5-including-multiple-worktrees-and-triangular-workflows):

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1319791/8943755/5dcdcae4-354a-11e5-9f82-915914fad4f7.png]

What you do is:

```
cd /path/to/local/repo
git remote add upstream /url/of/original/repo
git fetch upstream
```

That last fetch will include the new branch (in the `remotes/upstream` namespace)

From there, you can easily create a local branch starting from that `upstream/newBranch` and push it to your fork (referenced by the remote named '`origin`')

```
git checkout -b newBranch upstream/newBranch
git push -u origin newBranch
```